# Посчитать разницу во времени Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть дата

```
var timeNow = new Date();
```

и есть запись в бд с таким же форматом, полученная ранее:

```
"timeout": "2019-03-05T18:12:28.767Z"
```

Как можно узнать разницу во времени?
Если такой вариант не подходит, как правильно записывать дату в базу, чтобы потом было просто узнавать разницу?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {timeout : "2019-03-05T18:12:28.767Z"};
let timeNow = new Date();
let timeThen = new Date(obj.timeout);
console.log(timeNow - timeThen, 'milliseconds');
```

Comment: timeNow - timeThen = invalide date

Comment: @Danil, Вы, кнопку `Выполнить код`  "жмакали"?

Comment: у себя проверил, где-то значит ошибся. Спасибо за ответ!